# Sorting data after a little time

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can I next query to modify my data sorted in less time, (vice versa from this in this example).

This looks like the current result

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Z_PRAESENZZEIT
WHERE ZPZ_Datum = N'2019-02-11T00:00:00.000' and ZPZ_LPE_ID = 121
order by ZPZ_ID  ASC
```

I need to sort by ZPZ_ID and ZPZ_VON which is less than (ZPZ_Von:1899-12-30 10:00:00<1899-12-30 13:00:00

Comment: please add additional details about what your problem is

Comment: I should sort data  on the first  ZPZ_Von Time

Comment: Do you mean DESC, instead of ASC as you have in your query?

Comment: *"Sorting data in less time"* You mean optimize it so it runs faster?  Your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Z_PRAESENZZEIT WHERE ZPZ_Datum = N'2019-02-11T00:00:00.000' and ZPZ_LPE_ID = 121 and 
ZPZ_Von=N'1899-12-30T10:00:00.000' < N'1899-12-30T13:00:00.000' order by ZPZ_ID  ASC something of this

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM Z_PRAESENZZEIT
WHERE ZPZ_Datum = N'2019-02-11T00:00:00.000' and ZPZ_LPE_ID = 121
order by ZPZ_Von DESC, ZPZ_ID  ASC` something like that?

Comment: @ICospac That's right, something that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you do not want to sort in less time, i.e., more efficiently, but by times that are less than a given value.

```
SELECT *
FROM Z_PRAESENZZEIT
WHERE
    ZPZ_Datum = N'2019-02-11T00:00:00.000' and
    ZPZ_LPE_ID = 121
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ZPZ_Von < N'1899-12-30 13:00:00' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    ZPZ_ID
```

This will first list all the records with `ZPZ_Von` less than `1899-12-30 13:00:00` by `ZPZ_ID`, then all the others by `ZPZ_ID`. This `CASE` expressions creates two groups by which the records are sorted.

---

If you simply want to sort first by the time and then by the ID (if two or more records have the same time) then write

```
ORDER BY ZPZ_Von, ZPZ_ID
```

The default order is always ascending `ASC`, i.e., from small to big. If you want to reverse it, write `DESC`.

Comment: You are right, your answer is what I want. Is it possible to say: SELECT *
FROM Z_PRAESENZZEIT
WHERE
    ZPZ_Datum = N'2019-02-11T00:00:00.000' and
    ZPZ_LPE_ID = 121
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ZPZ_Von < ZPZ_Von THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    ZPZ_ID

Comment: You mean `ZPZ_Von < ZPZ_Bis`. Yes, you can use any condition to build groups.

Comment: No, I think that I take it as your example, to set up less time first. Do I have only one example, but I head the list in the database I have to sort this way.

Comment: `ZPZ_Von < ZPZ_Von` is always false because `ZPZ_Von` is never less than itself. These comparisons occur always within the columns of the same record. If you simply want to sort by `ZPZ_Von`, then by the ID, then simply write `ORDER BY ZPZ_Von, ZPZ_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some very easy ways to optimize data queries, but the ones that will be useful to you seem to be using ZPZ_LPE_ID as an identifier, it makes sense to have an index on that column (and be sure to rebuild the index so that it is actually improving speed).

```
ZPZ_Datum = N'2019-02-11T00:00:00.000'
```

is also suspect.  Looks like a date field, but you are using it like a string, so I'm going to assume it is not actually a date field.  String comparisons tend to be slower than date and numeric comparisons, so you should consider making this a date field and comparing it to a date.

Answer (score 0):

I would write your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Z_PRAESENZZEIT
WHERE ZPZ_Datum = '2019-02-11' and ZPZ_LPE_ID = 121
ORDER BY ZPZ_ID  ASC;
```

For this query, you want an index on `Z_PRAESENZZEIT(ZPZ_LPE_ID, ZPZ_Datum, ZPZ_ID)`.  This should satisfy both the `WHERE` and allow the `ORDER BY` to avoid a sort.